# Applescript: Use user inputs to get contact email from Address Book and add to Mail message

Tags: applescript, apple-mail

I would like to know what script I can use to add an email address of a person in Contacts to Mac Mail?

This is what I have thus far, it asks for various inputs and then uses these to compile a message. The rest of the code for the message works fine, but I would like the script to look for this person (based on the inputs), in Contacts and add the mail address listed there to the message in the To field:

```
--User Inputs to get Client details
display dialog "You are about to Create Outgoing e-mail for: Test

Please enter Client's First Name:" default answer "First Name"
set ClientName to text returned of result
display dialog "Please enter Client's Last Name:" default answer "Last Name"
set ClientLastName to text returned of result

--Create e-mail
tell application "Mail"
set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"Test", content:"Hi " & ClientName & ",
"}

tell theMessage
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:ClientName  & ClientLastName}
end tell
end tell
```

This creates the message and adds "ClientName + LastName" to To field, but I still have to go in and find the mail address. I would like Address Book to look up the person by First and Last Name and then add his address in the To field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this got out of hand quickly:

```
repeat
    display dialog "You are about to Create Outgoing e-mail for: Test
    Please enter Client's First Name:" default answer "First Name"
    set ClientName to text returned of result
    display dialog "Please enter Client's Last Name:" default answer "Last Name"
    set ClientLastName to text returned of result
    tell application "Address Book" to set myContact to every person whose first name is ClientName and last name is ClientLastName
    if myContact ≠ {} then
        exit repeat
    else
        display dialog "There is not match for " & ClientName & space & ClientLastName & " in your Address Book." buttons {"Try again", "Cancel"} default button "Try again"
    end if
end repeat

tell application "Address Book"
    if (count of myContact) > 1 then
        repeat with aPerson in myContact
            display dialog "More than one person in your Address Book is named " & ClientName & space & ClientLastName & ". Please select your contact..." & aPerson's vcard buttons {"Select", "Next", "Cancel"} default button "Select"
            if button returned of the result = "Select" then
                set myContact to contents of aPerson
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    else if (count of myContact) = 1 then
        set myContact to first item of myContact
    end if

    repeat
        set contactEmail to emails of myContact
        if contactEmail ≠ {} then
            exit repeat
        else
            display dialog "There is not an email listed for " & ClientName & space & ClientLastName buttons {"Cancel"} default button "Cancel"
        end if
    end repeat

    if (count of contactEmail) > 1 then
        set theEmails to {}
        repeat with anEmail in contactEmail
            set end of theEmails to label of anEmail & ": " & value of anEmail
        end repeat
        set contactEmail to first item of (choose from list theEmails with prompt "Please select an email address:")
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ": "
        set contactEmail to text item -1 of contactEmail
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    else if (count of contactEmail) = 1 then
        set contactEmail to value of first item of contactEmail
    end if
end tell

tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"Test", content:"Hi " & ClientName & ",
"}

    tell theMessage
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:contactEmail}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: sjees! Let me go through this quick and try it... Many thanks

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Works great. That saved me so much time